# How do I add a UIPickerView when tapping inside a text field?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

I have this code to add a datepicker:

```
// Initiate datepicker and assign to due date
_datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
[_datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
_datePicker.minuteInterval = 15;
_dueDate.inputView = _datePicker;
```

I tried to do the same thing with a pickerview but I had no success,  could somebody explain why?

Here is my code:
    // Initaite the pickerview and assign to priority text field
    _priorityPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 200)];

```
// Array otions for priority picker
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"High",@"Medium",@"Low", nil];
self.priorityPickerData = array;

// Connect text field to pickerview
_priority.inputView = _priorityPickerView;
```

Here is the data set in the picker view:

```
// Picker View functions
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponantsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [_priorityPickerData count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [self.priorityPickerData objectAtIndex:row];

}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    int select = row;
    if(select == 0){
        _priority.text = @"High";
    }else if(select == 1){
        _priority.text = @"Medium";
    }else if(select == 2){
        _priority.text = @"Low";
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance,

Peter

Comment: Does the app crash or does a keyboard come up?

Comment: Hi Abdullah, it doesn't crash, and the keyboard doesn't show.

Comment: Did you set the data for the picker view?

Comment: Yeah, I will update my question

Comment: Did you set the datasource and delegate to self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the delegate and datasource to self:

```
_priorityPickerView.delegate = self;
_priorityPickerView.dataSource = self;
```

Also at the top of your .m file:

```
@interface YourViewController ()<UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>
```

Comment: I will give that a go in a couple of minutes :)

Comment: That's twice today you have helped me! You are a legend! Thanks!